# Overflow In c

Tags: c, overflow, integer-overflow

I have a doubt

When two 16 bit values are added with max values, will there be overflow in the 16 bit machines?

I will elaborate

```
unsigned short a;
unsigned short b;
unsigned long  c;

c=(unsigned long)(a+b);
```

Talking about 16 bit processers the accumulator will be of 16 bit size. Will there be an  overflow in the above statement? Please clarify.

Comment: I fixed the most prominent spelling and formatting mistakes. Please put more work into asking a question on StackOverflow if you are expecting someone to answer.

Comment: you can't be sure of sizes of short and long unless the code is precisely only for architectures with known sizes. short could have the same size as long and then the cast will do nothing in adding safety (many machines will use 16bits for short and 32bits/64bits for long). use explicit sized types like uint16_t and uint32_t to avoid surprises.

Comment: most machines will use 16bits for unsigned short and 32bits for int. because a and b are automatically converted to int then anyway (usual arithmetical conversions), a + b won't overflow. That's probably the case on your machine too

Comment: litb: You are exactly right, assuming the compiler is of recent enough vintage to support uint16_t and so on.  On a 16 bit architecture, this may or may not be the case.

Answer (score 13):

With these definitions and assuming `unsigned short` == 16 bit and `int` == 16 bit and `unsigned long` == 32 bit (note that the size of `int` is important):

```
unsigned short a, b;
unsigned long  c;
```

These two statements will do different things:

```
c = (unsigned long)(a + b);
c = (unsigned long)a + b;
```

The first one -- the one you showed -- will first add the numbers as unsigned shorts, discarding any overflow -- and *then* expand to an unsigned long.  This may be why you're asking.  The second will cast `a` to an unsigned long, then add the two numbers, expanding `b` to an unsigned long as well before doing the addition.

You could also do this:

```
c = (unsigned long)a + (unsigned long)b;
```

but it's unnecessary as the presence of one unsigned long in the calculation will cause the other to be automatically promoted from short to long size.

Thus:

```
a = 0x8001;
b = 0x8001;
c = (unsigned long)(a + b);   /* c is assigned 0x00000002 */
c = (unsigned long)a + b;     /* c is assigned 0x00010002 */
```

All of this depends on your specific compiler and on the size of its variables.  It depends specifically on the size of an `int` on your compiler, as all values are automatically promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` during calculations.  You mentioned hardware with 16 bit accumulators, and C compilers will typically (but not always) use the native register size as the size of `int`, which is why I assumed an `int` as 16 bits.

Comment: The first form will not add them as `short`s. C has default promotions, so it will add them as `int`s. Except on systems with 16-bit `int` or very large `short`, there's no problem.

Comment: @R..: Yes, I was a bit imprecise in that first paragraph, but more precise later in my answer.  But I also explicitly assumed a 16 bit int as I explained, due to the OP mentioned 16 bit accumulators, so the result is the same either way with that assumption.  In fact, where int and short are the same size, you lose information when you add values both having the highest bit set in this scenario.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there will be an overflow. The subexpression a + b has type short, and only after it has been evaluated is the result cast to a long. Do this:

```
c = (unsigned long)a + b;
```

This will cause a to be cast to a long *before* the addition takes place, and this in turn will cause b to be cast to a long as well. Hence the addition of two longs takes place, and no overflow will occur.

Comment: Whether or not there will be an overflow depends on the size of int in the compiler in question. If int is the same size as unsigned, then you are correct.  If int is bigger than unsigned, then the variables will be automatically promoted to unsigned int before the calculation is done.

Comment: the answer's solution sounds easy, but it does not explain many pitfalls the questioner should be aware of :(

Comment: @litb: Is there anything I should add to this answer not already addressed by Eddie? I see you have a lot of rep: feel free to edit this answer.

Comment: i'm fine with how the state of affairs in the thread is currently :) I'll have to learn to write such to-the-point answers like you too. Thinking about it, i guess it's always good for the questioner if there are also short and to-the-point answers, so he first gets the "big picture" of the thing. Others can still write about the gory details :p cheers